# Problem using two font formats in Word header

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

From an subroutine in Excel, I am trying to create a header in a Word document with two words each with different font formatting however the last font formatting wins. Any help would be appreciated! Below is my current code snippet.

```
With myDoc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    .Font.Name = "Courier New"
    .Font.Size = 10
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Color = wdColorGreen
    .text = "TEXT LINE 1" & vbLf

    .Font.Name = "Calibri Light"
    .Font.Size = 16
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Color = wdColorBlack
    .text = .text & "TEXT LINE 2"
    ....the rest of the code....
```

**UPDATE:** I solved the issue by explicitly setting the range. See code snippet below.

```
With myDoc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    .Start = 0
    .text = "TEXT LINE 1" & vbLf
    .End = Len(.text)
    .Font.Name = "Courier New"
    .Font.Size = 10
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Color = wdColorGreen
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter

    .Start = Len(.text) + 1
    .text = "TEXT LINE 2"
    .End = Len(.text) + .Start
    .Font.Name = "Calibri Light"
    .Font.Size = 16
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Color = wdColorBlack
```

Comment: Right now it looks like you are applying first one format and then the other format to the *same* range, overwriting the first one.

Comment: Posting an answer as an edit/update to a question is frowned upon on Stack Overflow.The site's concept is Q&A, which means the question box should contain only a question and any answer belongs in the Answer box. You are allowed to answer your own question, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done a bit more efficiently / elegantly than the code posted in the "update". Relying on `Start` and `End` *values* is always a bit chancy with Word since Word can stick "hidden" content into the text flow. To get to the beginning or end of a `Range` it's more reliable to use `Collapse`. This will also be faster than doing calculations with values.

```
Dim rng as Word.Range
Set rng = myDoc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
With 
    '.Start = 0 'Not necessary as this will be the default position
    .text = "TEXT LINE 1" & vbLf
    '.End = Len(.text) 'Also not necessary, see further down...
    .Font.Name = "Courier New"
    .Font.Size = 10
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Color = wdColorGreen
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter

    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd 'put focus at end of range

    '.Start = Len(.text) + 1 'calculation not necessary as range has been collapsed
    .text = "TEXT LINE 2"
    '.End = Len(.text) + .Start 'not necessary
    .Font.Name = "Calibri Light"
    .Font.Size = 16
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Color = wdColorBlack
End With
```

Comment: Cindy, thanks so much! My original solution was using the Collapse method but I didn't specify the direction/constant. Now I see that if not specified, it defaults to wdCollapseStart which was causing me unexpected output. All makes sense now. Thanks again.